# PHP opendir works fine with relative path and not with absolute one?

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path, opendir

Here is the problem:
In one place I'm using relative path to load names of all files in certain folder:

```
if ($handle = opendir('images/uploads/form_id_1103/1'))
```

This is working fine, but if I change it to:

```
if ($handle = opendir('/images/uploads/form_id_1103/1'))
```

I get an error: **No such file or directory in** - just to mention, images folder is in the root, so /images should be valid

In the meantime, if I show an image from that ("non existing") folder with

```
<img src="/images/uploads/form_id_1103/1/test.jpg">
```

it works fine and shows the image.

I cannot use relative path, as I'm using Apache's mod_rewrite to transform URLs to SEO friendly ones.

Comment: Just use __DIR__.'/images/uploads/form_id_1103/1' and stop worrying. Use realpath(__DIR__.'/images/uploads/form_id_1103/1') to see the absolute path. Compare to what you got and see what went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing web URLs with file system paths. PHP's file-based functions dont' work with URLs, unless they're full+absolute `http://blah/blah/blah/blah`). You need to figure out the real path for your image on the server if you want to use an absolute one. It'd be something like

```
/home/site/example.com/docroot/images/etc...
                               ^---url starts here.
```

Comment: Thanks Marc!
I didn't even think to try this - I'm working on UBUNTU and adding /var/www in front solved that problem for my local machine.

I hope on the real hosting it will work with /images and not /public_html/images ... for example.

Comment: Just to clarify it, for someone else visiting this page, on shared hosting with cPanel, the real path for me is like this:
/home/<username>/public_html/images ...
where <username> is my username for cPanel logging

Answer (score 2):

If you start the path with a / on a Linux server. it will be processed as if you open the directory from the root of the linux installation. not relative to the current PHP file. a dot on the start of a path means the current directory.

Comment: Thanks PizzaMartijn too!
You are also pointing me real problem - / for the root of the linux installation.